# Convert MySQL result to an array strings

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting names of my products from products table in MySQL then I want to present these names to something like
 **`$names = array(name1, name2, ...)`**
 Where name1, ... are the names of the products from MySQL. I have gone through suggested similar cases but none seems to solve my problem. I am a newbie and just trying to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM products");
$names=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) $names[]=$row[0];
mysql_free_result($result);
```

You need the loop, as there is no way to directly get all rows of the complete result set.

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = mysql_query("

SELECT `productname` FROM `products`

")or die($result."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

    $numrows  = mysql_num_rows($result);  

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    $productname[$i] = $row['productname'];

            // to print out use the following
             echo $productname[$i];
            $i++;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, from an academic point of view, I suppose there's a "viable" alternative in doing something like

```
$names = explode('<|>', mysql_result(mysql_query(
    "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name separator '<|>') FROM products GROUP BY 'name'"
), 0));
```

All the power of loops and arrays in single line, for the low, low price of making baby Jesus cry. And yes, you should *probably* use a loop. Unless you have a phobia ever since a loop waited for you outside your school when you were little and beat you up, I guess.

Comment: from academic point of view one have to create a *function*. But it seems no PHP user (at least on this site) ever heard of such a feature.

Comment: Only if you intend to reuse the code. Otherwise functions themselves will lead to code bloat.

Comment: ..otherwise oneliner will make no sense. (Note that *this* case is among most reusable ones)

Comment: That depends on the application purpose. Functions are not a silver bullet. If you think it won't make sense, that falls under the `comment your code appropriately` clause of programming. Not that I advocate the use of this kind of code, just stating an opinion on practices.

Comment: this practice indeed requires an advocate

Answer (score -1):

Dunno why everione sticked to one-liner but anyway it's always good idea to make your code less bloated

create a function

```
  function dbGgetCol($sql) {
    $ret = array(); 
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql); 
    if ($res) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $ret[] = $row[0]; 
      }
      mysql_free_result($res); 
    }
    return $ret;
  }
```

place it in some config file included into each script
and then get your array with this simple code

```
$names = dbGetCol("SELECT name FROM products");
```